# How to overwrite one field of a schema with another in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, backend

how can I overwrite the value of officialLyric with the value of updateLyric??

```
artist: { type: String, required: true },
title: { type: String, required: true },
officialLyric: { type: String, required: true },
editedLyrics: [
  {
    updatedLyric: String,
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Aproved", "Rejected", "Pending"],
      default: "Pending",
    },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "User" },
  },
],
releaseDate: { type: Date },
```

see image for clear depiction of the question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOypi.png)

Comment: true, the editedLyrics array can hold many objects that hold updatedLyric, so i want any one of the updatedLyric to update the officialLyric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$arrayElemAt` to get first value of `updatedLyric` from `editedLyrics` array and update it into `officialLyric`

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {}, // put your query
  [{
    $set: {
      officialLyric: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$editedLyrics.updatedLyric", 0]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P5FFwI4CPXN)

Comment: I assume the 0 here ["$editedLyrics.updatedLyric", 0] is to indicate the first value of the array? so would it be possible to use 1, 2 ... depending on the position of the updatedLyric or it only works for the first one in the array?

Comment: yes it is index position of element in array, you can give any available index number.

Comment: this works like magic thanks @turivishal, is it possible to delete the updatedLyric after i used it to overwrite the officialLyrics? and thanks :)

Comment: *is it possible to delete the updatedLyric* => particular element's `updatedLyric` property or all the elements properties?

Comment: if its okay i would be grateful if you can show me both. otherwise i want to get rid that particular object that holds the updatedLyric inside the editedLyrics array that just overwrote the officialLyric

Comment: It would be great if you ask a new question, give chance to other stack overflow contributors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always have to value of latest updateLyric in editedLyric array in officialLyric, you don't need to actually store officialLyric in DB. you can use mongoose virtual fields and remove officialLyric from schema.

```
LyricSchema.virtual('officialLyric').get(function () { 
    if(!this.editedLyrics.length) return null;
    return this.editedLyrics[this.editedLyrics.length-1].updatedLyric;
});
```

If you still want to store the officialLyric first and then overwrite it with edited version you save. You can use hooks.

```
LyricSchema.post('save', async(error, doc, next) => {
    if(doc.editedLyrics.length && doc.officialLyric != doc.editedLyrics[doc.editedLyrics.length-1].updatedLyric){
        doc.officialLyric = doc.editedLyrics[doc.editedLyrics.length-1].updatedLyric;
        await doc.save();
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: the idea is, the officialLyric is going to hold a lyrics from the database but when a user assume that there is an error and should be updated, instead of automatically updating the officialLyric i want to store the change in the editedLyrics array and if i (the admin) deemed it good change i want the updatedLyric in the editedLyrics array to overwrite the officialLyric.